# Подключение роутеров с разными ip к одному компьютеру

Tags: сеть, wifi

У меня возник вопрос: почему до сих пор никто не сделал устройство объединяющее несколько роутеров с разным ip и провайдерами к одному компьютеру для увеличения скорости загрузки файлов? Я понимаю, что некоторые веб сайты будут работать некорректно. Например: на некоторых сайтах есть защита по ip. Если зайдешь с одного, потом со второго, первый ip де-аутентифицируется. Были бы проблемы с отправкой информации, но, например, с торрентами проблем возникнуть не должно

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: А зачем отдельное устройство? Куча роутеров это умеют делать.

Comment: И, в общем-то, кроме торрентов практического ускорения больше нигде не будет

Comment: Не совсем про устройства, но где-то рядом. Имея несколько сетевых карт на хосте, вы можете использовать протокол [SCTP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCTP)

Answer (score 0):

Как это никто не придумал? Есть MicroTik, в который можно воткнуть другие Микротики или любые другие устройства, раздающие интернет. Главное всё это настроить правильно.